# Android Apps Not Showing Up In AVD

Tags: android, virtual, device, android-virtual-device

I recently started messing with Android Apps, but I have had nothing but problems trying to get them into the Virtual Device for testing.  For some reason, they never seem to show up in the AVD.  It has worked one time, but that's it out of hours spent just trying to test one or two very simple apps.

I've redone the AVD setup many, many times, trying different settings and what not to no avail.  I've followed multiple guides and tutorials to the letter to get it working, but they just refuse to show up in the list. :(

Any insight would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: whats the output in the eclipse console tab? it will say something if an error occurs.  Also make sure that after the AVD launches you unlock the screen, the activity launcher doesn't do this automatically and your application won't come to the front till its unlocked.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by testing apps that are known to work. Here are [sixty or so of them](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android).

In particular, I would start with [this one](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Skeleton/Now/). Do not change anything. Do not import it into Eclipse. Just install Apache Ant (if you haven't already), and run `ant install` in the project directory with your emulator running.

Either this shows up in your emulator, or it does not.

If it does not, try reinstalling the entire SDK.

If it does, then you know that your base environment is OK, and you can start slowly determining the differences to figure out where things are going wrong.

Helping you is difficult right now because your symptoms are a bit generic. It could be that you are using Eclipse and Eclipse is having a problem. It could be that your `adb` daemon is having a problem. It could be that you don't have any activities in your manifest, so the application is actually installing but there are no icons in the launcher. And so on.

Comment: You always giving good answers... thanks for sharing your knowledge, I have learn too many things in your examples and books.